# Create a temporary table and loop through the rows in order to perform an update on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to alter data from an existing table into a temporary table and loop through the rows in order to perform an update on existing table data.

I need to strip down the DeviceName column and cast as an INT in order to extract the DevicesID's that will be needed in order to perform an update on an existing table. The first table shows an example of the unformatted DeviceName. The second table shows an example of the formated DeviceName (DeviceIntModified). I then need to get those DevicesID's so I can use them to perform an update on an existing table.

My original table `tblDevices`:

```
----------------------------------------------------
DeviceName          |   DevicesID   |   StationID
----------------------------------------------------
MainStation-464     |   1163        |   14
MainStation-465     |   1164        |   14
MainStation-466     |   1165        |   14
MainStation-467     |   1166        |   14
----------------------------------------------------
```

```
WITH tempTable as 
(
   SELECT
      DevicesID,
      RIGHT(DeviceName, LEN(DeviceName) - 12) AS DeviceNameModidfied
   FROM
      tblDevices 
   where
      StationID = 14 
)
select
   CAST (DeviceNameModidfied as int) as DeviceIntModified,
   DevicesID 
from
   tempTable 
where
   DeviceNameModidfied > 464 
   AND DeviceNameModidfied < 467
```

This works great and results in the following newly created `tempTable`:

```
----------------------------------
DeviceIntModified   |   DevicesID
----------------------------------
        465         |   1164
        466         |   1165
----------------------------------
```

I'm having issues selecting data from this tempTable and looping through the data.

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT WITH tempTable as 
(
   SELECT
      DevicesID,
      RIGHT(DeviceName, LEN(DeviceName) - 9) AS DeviceNameModidfied 
   FROM
      tblDevices 
   where
      StationID = 14 
)
select
   CAST (DeviceNameModidfied as int) as DeviceIntModified,
   DevicesID 
from
   tempTable 
where
   DeviceNameModidfied > 464 
   AND DeviceNameModidfied < 500 
SET
   @RowCount = 
   (
      SELECT
         COUNT(DevicesID) 
      from
         tempTable
   )
   DECLARE @I INT 
SET
   @I = 1 WHILE (@I <= @RowCount) 
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @rowID INT 
      --I'm getting invalid column/object name when trying to select from tempTable here
      SELECT
         @rowID = DevicesID 
      from
         tempTable 
         UPDATE
            anotherTable                
            SET CheckBox = 'T'
         WHERE
            DevicesID = @rowID 
         SET
            @I = @I + 1 
   END
```

The results should look something like this:
`anotherTable`:

```
----------------------------------
    CheckBox        |   DevicesID
----------------------------------
        T           |   1164
        T           |   1165
----------------------------------
```

Comment: Looping is almost always a bad idea in a DBMS; they are awful at such processes. A set based approach will very likely be hugely more effecient.

Comment: @Shane . . . It would really help if you explained *how you want to use the results of the first query*.  It is not obvious how this is being used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've edited my original post to explain this in better detail.

Comment: When I try your code I get `Invalid object name 'tempTable'.` .  That's because you have more than one statement in the context of a WITH, which is not allowed

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OP's first `WITH` clause, @user1443098 . I *suspect* the problem is the lack of a statement terminator on an earlier line: `DECLARE @RowCount INT;\r\nWITH tempTable as...` should be `DECLARE @RowCount INT WITH tempTable as...` (`\r\n` representing a new line).

Comment: There is at least one thing wrong with the WITH clause,  It must be preceded by a semicolon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql "When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon."  Plus there are multiple statements referencing the CTE, which is not allowed.

Comment: Calling a CTE `temptable` is a bit of an oxymoron as well; it is far from a temporary table. It's an expression.

Comment: @user1443098 *"It must be preceded by a semicolon"* makes it sound like `;WITH` is the correct statement. `WITH` (and `MERGE`) don't start with a semi colon; the previous statement **must** end with one. :)

Comment: Larnu is correct. The reason this failed was due to the Set statement. You can only use a CTE for one expression, and the SET statement was that expression. Therefore, the select has nothing to which to refer.

Comment: @SeanBrookins Hey, that's what I said, but I bet larnu was thinking about it.

Comment: Dang, @user1443098 - I can only edit for 5 minutes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a CTE directly, but in this case you can simply use an exists clause. The join criteria may be different if your example isn't exact. The exists clause is used over an inner join because you don't need to view the returned records which leads to this approach being preferable.

```
WITH tempTable as 
(
   SELECT
      DevicesID,
      RIGHT(DeviceName, LEN(DeviceName) - 12) AS DeviceNameModidfied
   FROM
      tblDevices 
   where
      StationID = 14 
)
, TempTable_2 as (
select
   CAST (DeviceNameModidfied as int) as DeviceIntModified,
   DevicesID 
from
   tempTable 
where
   DeviceNameModidfied > 464 
   AND DeviceNameModidfied < 467
)
Update SomeOtherTable
Set CheckBox = 'T'
where exists (select 1 from TempTable_2 tt where DeviceID = tt.DeviceID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid looping and even CTE's if you use the update syntax that allows you to join to 'anotherTable' right in the query itself.

```
update      other.checkbox = 't'
from        anotherTable other 
join        tblDevices td on td.devicesId = other.devicesId
cross apply (select DeviceNameMod = convert(int,right(DeviceName, len(DeviceName) - 12))) ap
where       td.StationID = 14 
and         ap.DeviceNameMod > 464 
and         ap.DeviceNameMod < 500;
```

But if you were to continue with your original approach, one of your big problems is that your @rowID is being used like an iterator, which should be from 0 to n-1 or from 1 to n, but you're populating it with 'DevicesId', which most certainly doesn't work that way.